# Entendiendo el indexOf

Tags: javascript

¿Porque al usar el metodo **indexOf** debe estar igualada a 0 la condición para encontrar las palabras que comiencen con "A"?

```js
let teachers =["Alexys",
                "Jon",
                "Daniel",
                "Francisco",
                "Rafa",
                "José",
                "Alvaro"];

for (i = 0; i < teachers.length; i++) {
    if (teachers[i].toUpperCase().indexOf("A") == 0) {
        console.log(teachers[i]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: entendiste el funcionamiento con los ejemplos que te comente?

Comment: En el codigo que se muestra a continuacion, tengo una duda del porque en la linea de codigo: pos2 = cadena.indexoF(separador,pos1); Por que indexOf() regresa valor de cero si el valor de separador es una cadena vacia (""). Dejo el codigo completo a continuacion. Como comentario el codigo funciona bien ya que se ajustaron las estructuras condicionales correspondientes. Sin embargo la duda, como ya se dijo es el comportamiento de la funcion indexOf() al momento de tratar de buscar un caracter vacio (""). Codigo completo: <script> //Variables var cadena = ""; var separador = ""; var arreglo = "";

Answer (score 14, accepted):

El método `indexOf` devuelve la posición en la cadena de la primera ocurrencia del valor pasado como parámetro (en este caso `"A"`).

Si no encuentra ninguna ocurrencia devuelve un valor de `-1`

`0` indicaría que existe una ocurrencia en la primera posición (primer carácter) de la cadena, `1` que existe en la segunda posición (segundo carácter), `2` en la tercera, etc.

De esta forma si la cadena comienza por `"A"` devolverá un valor de `0` y si no devolverá un valor diferente.

Más información: [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)

Comment: Entendí el concepto pero luego tengo estos ejemplos que me muestra MDN y no veo la lógica: "Blue Whale".indexOf("",9)      // returns 9
                                       "Blue Whale".indexOf("",10)     // returns 10
                                       "Blue Whale".indexOf("",11)     // returns 10

Comment: Por ejemplo si los parámetros superan la longitud del string. Ejemplo :  "Blue Whale".indexOf("",11) // returns 10

Comment: Y porque devuelve 10 si el string llega a i=9 y empieza a buscar desde i=11?

Comment: el siguiente parametro es ("") el asume que esta en la ultima posicion de la cadena ademas de que estas superando el limite de la cadena que es 9 mas la "" que estas buscando 10

Comment: Es un caso muy particular. El segundo parámetro acepta valores entre 0 y la longitud de la cadena (en este caso 10). Cualquier valor superior a éste se reemplaza automáticamente por la longitud de la cadena. Por eso `indexOf` en una cadena de longitud 10 devolverá el mismo valor con argumentos 10, 11, 12, 13, .... Si el primer argumento tiene una cadena todos estos casos devolverán -1, si es una cadena vacía devolverá un valor igual a la longitud (10 en este caso)

Answer (score 6):

La funcion **[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)** te retorna el primer indice que contienen una letra (en tu caso A). si no tiene valor devolvera **-1**

```js
console.log("alexys".indexOf("a"))
console.log("Papaya".indexOf("a"))

console.log("No tengo ->".indexOf("a"))
```

Javascript tiene otra forma y no tienes que hacer un for , usando el metodo [**Filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```js
let teachers =["alexys",
                "Jon",
                "Daniel",
                "Francisco",
                "Rafa",
                "José",
                "Alvaro"];
let soloA = teachers.filter(function(str){ 
                      return str.toUpperCase().startsWith('A')
            })
           
console.log(soloA)
```

Answer (score 6):

Porque **indexOf** se rige por la primera letra en tu ejemplo que deseas la "A" como primera letra, otros casos serian por ejemplo:

```js
 console.log("Asd".indexOf("A")) //devuelve 0 porque la A esta en la posición 0
                                // la cadena Asd la vería como ["A","s","d"]
    
console.log("Asd".indexOf("B")) // devuelve -1 porque "B" no se encuentra 
                                 //en la cadena

console.log("Dsd".indexOf("d")) //devuelve 2 porque la "d" se encuentra 
                                //en la posición 2 de la cadena
```

Es por esto que si buscas las palabras que **comiencen con una letra determinada** debes chequear la posición **0** de la cadena, que es la letra con que empieza.

> Nota: Fíjate en el tercer ejemplo que el método hace distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Si utilizas un segundo parámetro especificaras donde comenzaras a analizar la cadena, por ejemplo:

```
console.log('asd'.indexOf("s",0)) // este es el parámetro por defecto
                                   // se retornara 1(posición de "s")

console.log('asd'.indexOf("s",1)) // se comienza en la misma posición de "s"
                                  //   por tanto retornara 1

console.log('asd'.indexOf("s",2)) //en este caso se comenzara en la letra "d"
                                  //por lo que no se analizara "s" y retornara -1

console.log('asd'.indexOf("s",4)) //en el este caso de igual manera retornara -1 dado que estaría buscando en valores fuera de rango de la cadena

console.log("asd".indexOf("",4))  //en este caso al intentar realizar la búsqueda con un indice 
                    // mayor a la cantidad de elementos y como criterio de búsqueda ""
                     // se retornara 3 equivalente a la propiedad .length de la cadena
console.log('asd'.length) //3
```

Answer (score 5):

Las cadenas (strings) son arreglo de caracteres cuyos índices comienzan en 0, si deseas saber si una cadena comienza con una letra en específico debes verificar su primera aparición es decir el índice 0.