# ¿Cómo filtrar un objeto JSON complejo usando .filter()?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este JSON de ejemplo que contiene 2 elementos:

```
[
 {
   "Fecha":"2018-05-08T00:00:00",
   "Proyectado":0,
   "Requerido":0,
   "Faltante":0,
   "stock_resultado":0,
   "IdProducto":"88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56",
   "Consecutivo":184
 },
 {
   "__KEY__":"4a558959-bb63-68a2-2e87-358d678c6ec8",
   "Fecha":"2018/06/16 00:00:00",
   "Proyectado":2,
   "CantidadProyeccion":"8",
   "IdProducto":"7723EE8E-824C-7D19-1205-4B175D4A5DCB"
 }
]
```

Del anterior JSON necesito filtrar aquellos elementos cuyo `IdProducto` sea `88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56`.

He intentado usar la función "`filter`", pero siempre me devuelve la misma cantidad de datos *"para este caso, hay **(2) elementos** en el objeto"*.

Ejemplo de lo que intento hacer<sup>1</sup>:

```js
var arreglo_muestra = [{
  "Fecha": "2018-05-08T00:00:00",
  "Proyectado": 0,
  "Requerido": 0,
  "Faltante": 0,
  "stock_resultado": 0,
  "IdProducto": "88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56",
  "Consecutivo": 184
}, {
  "__KEY__": "4a558959-bb63-68a2-2e87-358d678c6ec8",
  "Fecha": "2018/06/16 00:00:00",
  "Proyectado": 2,
  "CantidadProyeccion": "8",
  "IdProducto": "7723EE8E-824C-7D19-1205-4B175D4A5DCB"
}];

function obtenerProductoPorId(IdProducto) {
  return IdProducto = "88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56";
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arreglo_muestra.filter(obtenerProductoPorId));
}
```

```html
<p>Presione el botón para obtener el objeto filtrado por IdProducto:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Filtrar producto por ID</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

La verdad no se porqué no funciona como supongo debe funcionar.

¿Cómo puedo filtrar este objeto de muestra usando `.filter()` u otra funcionalidad de javascript?

---

<sup>1</sup> Código adaptado de [esta página](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_filter).

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes aquí por *filtrar*? Si `IdProducto` es el mismo en ambos objetos no tiene ningún sentido filtrar, lo tendría si hubiera otros `IdProducto` distintos, en cuyo caso `filter`  te sacaría solamente aquellos con el valor que deseas.

Comment: @A.Cedano, tienes razón, he cambiado el `IdProducto` de uno de los elementos del objeto. He actualizado la pregunta. Gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mauricio, te propongo esta función:

```
function getFilteredByKey(array, key, value) {
  return array.filter(function(e) {
    return e[key] == value;
  });
}
```

Recibirá en parámetro el array, la llave y el valor que quieres filtrar y te devolverá el resultado.

Creo que de este modo el código podría ser más portable.

He aplicado una práctica que a mi me parece recomendable: liberar los elementos del DOM de cualquier función, relegándola a un *listener* por su id, de ese modo, los elementos del DOM quedan más independientes.

```js
var btnFilter = document.getElementById("btnFilter");

btnFilter.onclick = function() {
  var arreglo_muestra = [{
    "Fecha": "2018-05-08T00:00:00",
    "Proyectado": 0,
    "Requerido": 0,
    "Faltante": 0,
    "stock_resultado": 0,
    "IdProducto": "88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56",
    "Consecutivo": 184
  }, {
    "__KEY__": "4a558959-bb63-68a2-2e87-358d678c6ec8",
    "Fecha": "2018/06/16 00:00:00",
    "Proyectado": 2,
    "CantidadProyeccion": "8",
    "IdProducto": "7723EE8E-824C-7D19-1205-4B175D4A5DCB"
  }];

  var filteredProducts = getFilteredByKey(arreglo_muestra, "IdProducto", "88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56");
  console.log(filteredProducts);

  var elDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
  elDemo.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(filteredProducts, null, 4) + "</pre>";

};


function getFilteredByKey(array, key, value) {
  return array.filter(function(e) {
    return e[key] == value;
  });
}
```

```html
<p>Presione el botón para obtener el objeto filtrado por IdProducto:</p>

<button id="btnFilter">Filtrar producto por ID</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo dice la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) , debes recibe un elemento y dentro de el la condicion que se debe cumplir, ten en cuenta que te retornara otro arreglo de objetos, puede sero con cero elementos o varios

```js
var arreglo_muestra = [{
  "stock_resultado": 0,
  "IdProducto": "A",
  "Consecutivo": 184
}, {
    "IdProducto": "B"
}];

function obtenerProductoPorId() {
  return IdProducto = "A";
}
function buscarID(element) {
    return element.IdProducto == obtenerProductoPorId();
}


solucion = arreglo_muestra.filter(buscarID )
console.log(solucion)
console.log("resultado solicion " + solucion.length)
```

> Puedes [ver otro ejemplo usando filter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138014/28035)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  const mi_muestra = JSON.parse(arreglo_muestra)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mi_muestra.filter(obtenerProductoPorId())
}
```

Comment: tu ejemplo no funciona, podrias completarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función flecha, la solución es un poco mas corta, en esta solución aplicamos la función `filter` a la variable `array`, pasando como parámetro cada objeto representado como `e` entonces la función `filter` recorrerá cada objeto dentro del arreglo filtrando el `IdProducto` de cada elemento recorrido y retornando el resultado conforme a la condición.

Aquí la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```js
let array = [
 {
   "Fecha":"2018-05-08T00:00:00",
   "Proyectado":0,
   "Requerido":0,
   "Faltante":0,
   "stock_resultado":0,
   "IdProducto":"88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56",
   "Consecutivo":184
 },
 {
   "__KEY__":"4a558959-bb63-68a2-2e87-358d678c6ec8",
   "Fecha":"2018/06/16 00:00:00",
   "Proyectado":2,
   "CantidadProyeccion":"8",
   "IdProducto":"7723EE8E-824C-7D19-1205-4B175D4A5DCB"
 }
];

let arrayFilter = array.filter(e => e.IdProducto == "88C9B788-2009-47B3-5690-532E2CF84E56")

console.log(arrayFilter)
```