# Como filtrar con ng-repeat en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como puedo hacer un `filter` para aquellos `items` que tengan `offers`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $document) {

    $scope.items = [
        {
            id: 0,
            description: "Primer Item 1",
            offers: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "Casa"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            description: "Segundo Item 2"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            description: "Quinto Item 5"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            description: "Sexto Item 5",
            offers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Bodega"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            description: "Septimo Item 6"
        }
    ];

    $scope.filterItem = function() {
        
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="propertyOffer" ng-model="propertyOffer" ng-click="filterItem()">Item con oferta
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{ item }}
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: puedes usar el filter.. como usarlo? [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/175777/28035) varias respuestas!

Comment: @JackNavaRow me puedes ayudar en algo bro :v realice esta pregunta para hacer una idea pero aun no doy con una conclusión correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer agregando la directiva ***ng-if***, seria la forma mas fácil para este simple caso ya que no necesitas código adicional. Con solo envolver los *items* en un `<div>`, de la siguiente forma:

```
<div ng-if="!propertyOffer || item.offers">
            {{ item }}
</div>
```

La expresión `!propertyOffer || item.offers` sera siempre *true*, cuando el *checkbox* no este chequeado, por lo que mostrara todos los *items*. En caso de ser "checkeado" pasara a dar *false* (`!propertyOffer`) y mostrara solo los *items* que tengan *offers* ya que se evaluara en *true* (`item.offers`)

> ***ng-if:*** La directiva `ngIf` elimina o recrea una parte del árbol DOM
>   basada en una {expresión}. Si la expresión asignada `ngIf` evalúa a un
>   valor falso, entonces el elemento se elimina del DOM, de lo contrario,
>   un clon del elemento se re inserta en el DOM.
>
> La sintaxis es: `ng-if="expresión"`

---

### Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $document) {

    $scope.items = [
        {
            id: 0,
            description: "Primer Item 1",
            offers: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "Casa"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            description: "Segundo Item 2"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            description: "Quinto Item 5"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            description: "Sexto Item 5",
            offers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Bodega"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            description: "Septimo Item 6"
        }
    ];

    $scope.filterItem = function() {
        
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="propertyOffer" ng-model="propertyOffer" ng-click="filterItem()">Item con oferta
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <div ng-if="!propertyOffer || item.offers">
            {{ item }}
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```