# Encontrar valor en array JSON

Tags: jquery

Estoy haciendo un programa para una cerezeria que manda barriles vacios a llenar.

en el formulario de stock se ingresa el tipo de cerveza y un numero de barril. entonces obtengo un JSON  de la tabla barriles mediante una peticion AJAX.
Y quiero comprobar si el campo "activo" de la tabla barril de ese idbarril esta en 1, osea si esta vacio es posible llenarlo.:
Al cargar el formulario de stock tengo:

```js
    var accion= "barriles";
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/stock/procesostock.php",
                data:{"accion":accion},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                barriles=data;
      
                if (!data.length===0){
                    alert("no hay envases vacios");
                }
                }
                });
```

```js
 function compruebaBarril(){
            for (var i = 0; i < barriles.length; i++) {
                
                if (barriles[i].idbarril===barril){
        
                                    }
                }}
```

La funcion de arriba quiero llamar al hacer click en confirmar, si esta disponible el barril continuo el proceso. Pero no se bien como hacer..gracias

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo filtrar un objeto JSON complejo usando .filter()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175773/c%c3%b3mo-filtrar-un-objeto-json-complejo-usando-filter)

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver el objeto que mandas como respuesta del Ajax es difícil decirte como buscar el valor de activo. Pero puedo decirte cómo podrías buscarlo.

Lo primero sería devolver un objecto a la respuesta del ajax y después parsearlo a JSON.

`var barriles = JSON.parse(data);`

Una vez tengas el resultado puedes imprimir en consola para ver que es lo que tienes y cómo tienes que sacarlo. Para ello utilizas esto:

```
console.log(barrilles);
```

Ahora pulsas F12 en el navegador y abres la consola. Aquí podras ver cual es la estructura de tu objeto y cómo sacar los datos.